# How to extract a line of pixels (roi) from video, combined lines in a single .tif image?

Tags: python, line, jython, imagej, roi

I am new to programming and I am trying to use ImageJ and Jython to extract a single line from a video and combine the lines into a time progression. I am trying to create a videokymogram (i.e. http://www.kymography.com/supp_demo.html)!

My attempt goes like this:

```
from ij import ImagePlus, IJ
from ij.process import FloatProcessor

img = IJ.getImage() 
roi = img.getRoi()
StackSize = 100  #img.getImageStackSize() 

pixels = roi.getPixels()
Length = len(pixels)
Width = 1

total_pixels = [[0] *len(pixels)] * StackSize
t_pixels = []


for j in range (1, StackSize):
    img.setSlice (j)
    roi = img.getRoi()
    pixels = roi.getPixels()
    for i in xrange (len(pixels)):
        pixels [i] = pixels [i] 
    total_pixels[j-1] = pixels 

fp = FloatProcessor (Length, StackSize,total_pixels)
imp = ImagePlus ("White Noise", fp) 
imp.show()
```

However it returns: 
TypeError: ij.process.FloatProcessor(): 3rd arg can't be coerced to double[], int[], float[]

Any tips on how to fix that. I could maybe iterate a text file appending the pixels variable but I don't know how to do it. 
Any help is welcomed. 
BTW, if you want to try it, you can use Fiji's Fly Brain sample.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get suggests that `total_pixels` is not an array of type double[], int[] or float[], which is needed for any of the constructors of the [`FloatProcessor`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/process/FloatProcessor.html) class.

A nice way to build Java arrays in Python is using jarray, the Jython module for Java arrays, as outlined in the [Jython Scripting](http://fiji.sc/Jython_Scripting#Creating_a_random_8-bit_image) documentation of the Fiji wiki.

I modified your code, which also needed some fixing within the `for` loops:

```python
from ij import ImagePlus, IJ
from ij.process import FloatProcessor
from jarray import zeros

img = IJ.getImage() 
roi = img.getRoi()
stackSize = img.getImageStackSize() 

pixels = roi.getPixels()
length = len(pixels)

total_pixels = zeros(length * stackSize, 'f')

for j in xrange (stackSize):
    img.setSlice (j+1)
    roi = img.getRoi()
    pixels = roi.getPixels()
    for i in xrange (length):
        total_pixels[j*length+i] = pixels [i]

fp = FloatProcessor (length, stackSize, total_pixels)
imp = ImagePlus ("White Noise", fp) 
imp.show()
```

FWIW, other people have used ImageJ to work with kymographs: you can find a [tutorial on the Fiji wiki](http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Generate_and_exploit_Kymographs) as well as some [plugins producing kymographs](http://www.embl.de/eamnet/html/kymograph.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for fixing the script. Also thanks for the tip!!

Comment: Hi Jan, I am trying to save the new image of the kymograms into a folder according to [http://www.ini.uzh.ch/~acardona/fiji-tutorial/index.html#s1] using: 

`imp = IJ.getImage()  
fs = FileSaver (imp)    
folder = "C:/Users/myfolder/Desktop/ImageJ_files"  
filepath = folder + "/" + "Videokymogram.tiff"  
fs.saveAsTiff(filepath)'  

It produces an empty image with nothing inside. 
Is it possible to fix it? thanks once again

Comment: Try `IJ.saveAsTiff(imp, path)` (see the [javadoc for Filesaver.saveAsTiff](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/ij/io/FileSaver.html#saveAsTiff%28java.lang.String%29)). If that doesn't work, just open a new question with more details. Also, consulting the [ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.net/list.html) often helps, since there are many more ImageJ expert readers than on stackoverflow.